# JMeter - Recurring request every x seconds without blocking other requests

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to load test our web app server side with JMeter, everything works so far except one thing.
I have a heartbeat loop the app client side that pings the server every x seconds.

I tried the while processor but then the thread is just "stuck" there (as expected).
Is there a way to execute a request every x seconds while the other requests are still executing?

I also would need access to the variables of my thread since the heartbeat sends a unique id, so another thread group won't work as far as i understand.
The id is read from one of the first request responses into a variable so the heartbeat requests should only start when this variable becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

Another separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to send heartbeat requests is the easiest way to achieve, if you need to pass a value from the "main" thread group you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the "main" thread group to convert the variable into a property and use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in 2nd Thread Group to read the value. If you have more than 1 thread it makes sense to add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) to make the value thread-specific.
2. Use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](http://How%20to%20Use%20the%20Inter-Thread%20Communication%20Plugin%20in%20JMeter) if you don't mind using JMeter Plugins