# Authorization request run every x minutes, while load test continues

Tags: jmeter

[image: Test Plan]I have an API that needs the authorization header - auth expires after 10 minutes

API to be load tested just needs to run the auth header request every 10 minutes - and pass that auth token. I have the variable set up correctly, but am unable to get the auth to re run at 10 minutes

[This is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306578/jmeter-recurring-request-every-x-seconds-without-blocking-other-requests) but is different enough that I am asking my question

This is the logic in the **JSR223 Post Processor**

```
def start_Time = vars.get("startTime")
log.info "start_Time>>>>>>>"+start_Time

long currentTime = ${__time(,)}
log.info "currentTime>>>>>>>"+currentTime;

long diff=currentTime.toLong()-start_Time.toLong();
log.info "diff>>>>>>>"+diff

if(diff>=100){
    start_Time = ${__time(,)};
    vars.put("startTime",start_Time.toString());
}
vars.put("flag",diff.toString());
log.info "FlagValue>>>>>>>"+vars.get("flag")
```

which doesn't seem to be correct, I have seen some threads on this, but haven't been able to find the problem with the above.

Logic in the **If Controller**

```
${__groovy(vars.get("flag").toInteger() >= 100)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

Your [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function call returns the same value each time, you need to replace it with [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) function

So I believe your code needs to be changed to look like:

```
def start_time = vars.getObject('startTime') ?: vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long

def currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

def diff = currentTime - (start_time as long)

if (diff >= 100) {
    vars.putObject('startTime', System.currentTimeMillis())
}

vars.putObject('flag', diff)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks so much for this Dmitri!

It's very close, but as mentioned in the beginning, the auth needs to be run after 10 minutes. 

So when the if statement is `if (diff >= 100) {...` it runs a lot more than it should

How do I convert these to seconds instead of millis?

Comment: maybe multiplying by 1000 ...

Comment: I tried adding * 1000, and got `Cannot invoke method toInteger() on null object`

Comment: It means that your `flag` variable is not defined, check [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file for any suspicious entries and use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) before the If Controller to see what [JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) are defined with their respective values